# Can you create an ITracingService?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I have a Dynamics CRM plugin I'm trying to debug in Linqpad. I can reference my plugin assembly but it requires an ITracingService object. Can I create one and set its output location to the console?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You implement the `ITracingService` interface on a class.

```
public class NullCrmTracingService : ITracingService
{
    public void Trace(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Best simple solution